# How to overload and use two different operators simultaneously in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-arrays, brackets

I want to redefine the two operators bracket "[]" and equal "=" in C++ language and use them simultaneously.
In fact, I want to create a dynamic array and use it like usual arrays in C++ language. For example, do the assignment like normal arrays.
For example:

```
MyDynamicArray myarray;
myarray[0] = 1;
myarray[1] = 7;
myarray[2] = 3;
```

What is important to me is the redefining of the assignment and bracket operators and their simultaneous use within my code.

My dynamicarray.h file is:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename anyType>
class DynamicArray {
    private:
        Linear_Singly_Linked_List<anyType> *D_Arr;
        bool assignmentflag;
    public:
        DynamicArray() {
            D_Arr = new Linear_Singly_Linked_List<anyType>;
            assignmentflag = false;
        }
        unsigned int GetNumberOfNodes() {
            return D_Arr->get_number_of_nodes();
        }
        void Store(unsigned int index, anyType object);
        anyType operator = (anyType object) {
            if (assignmentflag) 
                D_Arr->append(object);
        }
        anyType operator [] (unsigned int index) {
            return D_Arr->display_of_data_node(index + 1);
            assignmentflag = true;
        }
};

template<class anyType> void DynamicArray<anyType>::Store(unsigned int index, anyType object) {
    if (D_Arr->get_number_of_nodes() == index) {
        D_Arr->append(object);
    }
    else if (index >= 0 && index < D_Arr->get_number_of_nodes()) {
        D_Arr->replacement(index+1,object);
    }
    else if (index > D_Arr->get_number_of_nodes()) {
        for (unsigned int i = D_Arr->get_number_of_nodes() ; i < index ; i++) {
            anyType nul = NULL;
            D_Arr->append(/*NULL*/nul);
        }
        D_Arr->append(object);
    }
}
```

and my dynamicarrayTester.cpp file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dynamicarray.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    DynamicArray<int> a;

    a[0] = 27;

    a.Store(0,-7);
    a.Store(1,-5);
    a.Store(2,3);
    a.Store(3,2);

    a[3] = 7;

    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << a[1] << endl;
    cout << a[2] << endl;
    cout << a[3] << endl;
}
```

In the part where `a[0] = 27;` I get "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. To allow modifications you must return a reference.

Comment: Reinventing `std::vector` for fun and profit? A linked list is a *horrible* idea. Don't. In any case you should not allocate the list itself dynamically. Your class violates the law of 3/5/0, which is quite literally the very first thing any C++ programmer should learn.

Comment: Dear friend [n. m.], thank you for your advice.
I am a beginner. I know that using a linked list in this project is not a good idea and reinventing the wheel, but I am doing this project for my homework. Please don't blame me. Bad behavior causes annoyance and discomfort.
But thank you very much for your help. I don't know the 3/5/0 rule. Please send me the link to the explanation of this law. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: `operator[]()` and [preferably, although technically optional in your usage] `operator=()` need to return a reference (to an existing element of your `DynamicArray`).   They are both returning by value, so the result of `operator[]()` cannot be used as an lvalue (placed on the left hand side of an assignment).    Also the assignment `AssignmentFlag = true` in `operator[]()`  is never executed since it is immediately AFTER a return statement - the flow of execution never reaches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overload `operator[]` to return a reference.  E.g.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Arr {
    T *data;
    std::size_t size;

public:
    Arr(std::size_t size) : data(new T[size]), size(size) { }

    ~Arr() { delete [] data; }

    T & operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return data[i];
    }
};

int main() {
    Arr<int> arr{10};

    arr[3] = 42;

    std::cout << arr[3] << std::endl;
}
```